# Adding DateTime Lookup on a Django FilterSet

Tags: django, django-filter

with the new django-filter v2 coming out. I was wondering how i could replicate the below functionality with it.

Before my filterset was as so

```
class PostFilterSet(filters.FilterSet):
    date = filters.DateFilter(
           name='date',
           lookup_expr=DATETIME_LOOKUPS,
           method='filter_date')

    class Meta:
         # Meta Options here

    def filter_date(self, queryset, name, value):
         # filter logic
```

What this would essentially let me do on the api is make filter request like this 'https://example.com/api/post/?date__gt=exampledate' but with the latest update i can no longer keep the list of DATETIME_LOOKUPS and have to use the Lookup choice filter which changed the request to 'https://example.com/api/post/?date=exampledate&date_lookup=exact' is there a way to make it work like it did before in a painless way ?

Comment: do you mean that you want your `date` filter to filter simply with `date__gt`?

Comment: @robtus88 Hey, Sorry wasn't to clean i mean i want `date` to filter with `gt`, `gte`, `lt` , `lte` and many other lookups at the same time.